# Get Unresolved Identifier for MMWormhole in Watch InterfaceController.swift

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, bridge, mmwormhole

My Apple Watch project is in Swift.  I have used CocoaPods to install MMWormhole, 
and I created the bridging header as described in these links:

http://bencoding.com/2015/04/15/adding-a-swift-bridge-header-manually/

[How to call Objective-C code from Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift)

When I created the bridging header, I target it to my iphone app, and also watch Extension.

The bridging header.h, I have this:

```
#import "MMWormhole.h"
```

In my iPhone app View Controller, I have this:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation 

let wormhole = MMWormhole(applicationGroupIdentifier: "group.cocoShareData", optionalDirectory: "wormhole")
```

and there is no complain.

However, in my watch Interface Controller, I have this:

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation

...

override func willActivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
        super.willActivate()
        let wormhole = MMWormhole(applicationGroupIdentifier: "group.cocoShareData", optionalDirectory: "wormhole")
}
```

And it complains about "Use of unresolved identifier MMWormhole".

I even try to use #import "MMWormholeClient.h"   but nothing can resolve this problem.

I also try when creating the bridging header, just target on the iphone App.  But still... doesn't work.

I also make pod 'MMWormhole', '~> 1.2.0'  in the podfile target for WatchExtension.   but still not identified MMWormhole in the Watch interfaceController

Am I missing something ?

here is my project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/tsajeoopnghyl1g/MyTestCocoData.zip?dl=0

Comment: I am having the same problem. All MMWormhole getting started guides seems to be missing this part.

Comment: @JohanKarlsson did you solve your problem?

Comment: @swalkner I did not get this to work. Used other solution.

Comment: in the meantime I found a solution: was missing ```import MMWormhole``` in the swift file. Thought it's enough to have it in the bridging header...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my answer.  After few days of struggle and help from a code mentor:

Problems are:

```
1) The Objective-C bridge has to set the correct path and header search path so both IOS & WatchExt can use
2) The PodFile in MMWormhole must target for both iOS & WatchExt. 
3) The code in MMWormhole npm page is not correct.  Move the instantiation of MMWormhole out and be a class Variable.
```

Here is the brief step by step:

**Objective C Bridge**

- Add App Groups for both iPhone App & Watch Ext
- Add Objective C
- Target on both
- Build Settings: Set the *.h in relative path for both iOS & Watch Ext. set the *.h relative path. e.g.
  ../MMWormholeTest/MMWormholeTest/MMWormholeTest-Bridging-Header.h
- Add Header Search path:  ${PRODS_ROOT}/Headers  , recursive  for both IOS 7 Watch Ext

**MMWormhole**

- Cocoa pods it.
- Set pod 'MMWormhole', '~> 1.2.0’  target for both iOS & Watch Ext in Podfile
- Set #import “MMWormhole.h” in bridging header file.
- in both ViewController & InterfaceOController, set wormhole as class scope variable.  e.g. var wormhole:MMWormhole!
- Instantiate MMWormhole in ViewDidLoad and awakeWithContext
  in WatchExt, set listener in awakeWithContext  , and use self.lable.setText  because of closure. e.g.  self.label.setText(messageObject! as! String)
- No need to register receiver as shown in some other MMWormhole examples in Stack overflow.